# How to delete the word from Microsoft word document using vb.net software?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

Its not finding & replacing the word i want the code that can find initial characters of the word & replace complete word with other string

here is the code i am using to find & replacing the word from the Document

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
        objWordApp = New Word.Application
        Dim TLA_name = "TL"
        Dim objDoc As Word.Document
        Dim rng As Word.Range
        'Show the Word application window if checked.
        objWordApp.Visible = True

        'Open an existing document.
        objWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\SLLD-SW-230-MNS.docx")
        objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument
        rng = objDoc.Content
        rng.Find.Text = "TLA"
        rng.Find.Replacement.Text = TLA_name
        rng.Find.Execute(ReplaceWith:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)

        'Find and replace some text.
        objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="DDD_MNS_", _
             ReplaceWith:=TLA_name, _
             Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne)
        While objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", _
            Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
            objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", ReplaceWith:=" ", _
                Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, _
                Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
        End While

        'Save and close the document.
        objWordApp.Documents.Item(1).Save()
        Console.WriteLine("Replaced all instances of 'VB' with 'Visual Basic Express' " & _
            "and saved the document")

        objWordApp.Documents.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        objWordApp.Quit()
        objWordApp = Nothing

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? I can see the document is opened programmatically but it's not saved.

Comment: hi charli sorry that code was just a snapshot document saving & closing is done

Comment: Hi charli now can you see that i have corrected the code

Comment: do you know how i can do this